# Probability drawing cards from deck with 52 and choosing balls of same color.

Tags: probability

I just started out with probability and a problem in my text book bugs me:

From a deck with 52 cards one is being selected. If the card that was selected is a club then 2 balls will be selected (simultaneously) from a box with 2 white and 3 black balls. In all other cases (for the cards) also 2 balls are selected from a box with 4 white and 1 black.

a) find the probability that the balls will be of the same color.

b) If you know that the balls are of different color, find the probability that the selected card was a club.

---

A - the event that the selected card is a club

B - the event that the balls have the same color

Now I know that A and B are under conditional probability. So applying

$P(B)=P(A)P(B|A)+P(A^c)P(B|A^c)$

I should get P(B) and that is also how my textbook does it however, how can I calculate it in this way if I don't know how much P(B|A) is? It might be that my textbook skipped some steps but there it looked like P(B|A) and the other one were known values. Can someone elaborate this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(\text{same color}) &= P(\text{all black})+P(\text{all white})\\
                     &= P(\text{club})P(\text{all black}|\text{club})+P(\text{other})P(\text{all black}|\text{other})\\
&\hspace{10mm}+P(\text{club})P(\text{all white}|\text{club})+P(\text{other})P(\text{all white}|\text{other}) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{{3\choose 2}}{{5\choose 2}}+0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{{2\choose 2}}{{5\choose 2}} + \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{{4\choose 2}}{{5\choose 2}} \\
&=\frac{11}{20}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this as two separate events which can then be added together to get the final answer:

**First event**

The card drawn is a club which has probability $\cfrac{13}{52}=\cfrac 14$

Then we need to calculate the probability of drawing two balls of the same colour from a box containing $2$ white and $3$ black balls. This can be done in one of two ways: we draw $2$ white balls or we draw $2$ black balls:

\begin{align}P(\text{both balls same colour})&=P(2\text{ black balls}) + P(2\text{ white balls})\\
&=\frac 35 \times \frac 24+\frac25\times \frac14\\
&=\frac 3{10}+ \frac1{10}\\
&=\frac 4{10}
\end{align}

So, event $1$ has a probability of $$\frac14\times\frac4{10}=\frac1{10}$$

**Second event**

The card drawn is not a club which has probability $1-\cfrac14=\cfrac34$

Then we need to calculate the probability of drawing two balls of the same colour from a box containing $4$ white and $1$ black ball. This can only be done in one way: we draw $2$ white balls:

\begin{align}P(\text{both balls same colour})&=P(2\text{ white balls})\\
&=\frac45\times\frac34\\
&=\frac 35
\end{align}

So, event $2$ has a probability of $$\frac 34\times\frac 35=\frac 9{20}$$

**Conclusion**

Therefore, we can say that the overall probability of of drawing two balls of the same colour is $$\frac1{10}+\frac9{20}=\frac{11}{20}$$